# Why does StringBuffer allows StringBuffer as argument to its constructor even when StringBuffer doesn't have a StringBuffer constructor?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

Why is the below line not giving a compile time error?

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(new StringBuffer());
```

I did enough online search but couldn't find the reason. Not just this it is also allowing StringBuider argument
`StringBuffer sb2 = new StringBuffer(new StringBuilder());`

Someone please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder` implements the interface `CharSequence` and the `StringBuffer` has a constructor for that interface.

Comment: Thanks for that, it's helpful